# VBA loop thru consecutively numbered names

Tags: vba, for-loop

I know how to loop through numbers in parentheses like

```
For i = 0 To (ComboBox4.ListCount - 1)
If ComboBox4.Value = ComboBox4.List(i) Then inList = True
Next i
```

But how can I loop through numbers that are not in parentheses? Like consecutively numbered names:

```
Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox3.Value = ""
```

I tried:

```
for i=1 to 3
"Me.ComboBox"&i&".Value" = ""
next i
```

But that does not work. How should it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the controls-function:

```
Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value = 'your code...
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd use the [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.controls) collection.

E.g.:

```
Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i)
```

**Edit:**
As the controls on a form are part of a collection you can also iterate through the collection pulling each control in turn:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        Dim ctl As Control

        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is MSFORMS.ComboBox Then
'           If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
                MsgBox ctl.Name
            End If
        Next ctl

    End Sub
```

I've added two ways to identify the control type as suggested by @CallumDA.

[Microsoft writes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/determining-object-type):

- The `TypeName` function returns a string and is the best choice when you need to store or display the class name of an object.
- The `TypeOf...Is` operator is the best choice for testing an object's type, because it is much faster than an equivalent string comparison using TypeName.

Comment: FWIW I think `TypeOf` is better than `TypeName`, which can give you false positives in some circumstances. E.g. `If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then`... in this case I'm sure TypeName works just fine though. +1

Comment: @CallumDA I used `TypeName` because I always forget what it's called and that's the first one that Google suggests.  `TypeOf` is the better for testing an objects type though.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I’ll never forget when I learned about Controls. My code went from thousands of copy/paste error prone lines to a handful robust easy to troubleshoot lines. Game changer for sure.